# get largest number in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

I think I need a second pair of eyes to take a look at this as I can't see what I'm doing wrong :-(

I'm trying to get the bigesst value using a simple function, but the results are not what I'm expecting.

Here is the code...

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract GetBiggest {

uint public val1 = 1;
uint public val2 = 2;
uint public val3 = 3;
uint public val4 = 0;



        function getBiggestValue() public view returns(uint) {

            uint x = val1;


            if(x < val2) {
                    x = val2; 

                }

            if(x < val3) {
                    x = val3; 

                }

            if(x < val4) {
                    x = val4; 

                }

        }

}
```

I'm expecting the value of 3 to be returned when I call the function, but I get 0

What's up with this?

thanks

Comment: Where's the `return` statement??? I wonder how this code even compiles...

Comment: @goodvibration The code compiles because there is a default value set for every typecast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply missing the `return x;` statement at the end.